# Magento 2 Generate static files without gulp

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, sass

Has anyone tried to generate static sass files without gulp?
I want to do the same as when I execute the following commands...

- gulp deploy --theme Namespace/Theme
- gulp sass --theme Namespace/Theme

Also, I've tried with...

- cd pub/static && find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete
- rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

... but my css and js files are not generated.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 does not come with Sass support out the box, for it to work with `static-content-deploy` you would need to add your own adapter. Instructions for that can be found on the official dev docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/custom_preprocess.html)